# Android Overflow Menu Icon Foreground color

Tags: android, overflow-menu

How can i get the overflow menu icon (three dots) in the actionbar programmatically? I want to change the foreground color dynamically. I can change the color of the other menu items with an icon but not the overflow menu icon.

Comment: If you found out how to reach it, let me know. I have to do the same thing, I found that I could edit other menu options in onCreateOptionsMenu... but can't seem to fetch the overflow icon

Comment: toolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainHomeActivity.this, R.drawable.dots_vertical));                                                                                   Have you tried this ......